# "As a team" or "like a team"?

Tags: grammaticality, as-like

I was going through some English page with grammar where I saw their explanation to a problem *when to say 'as'/'like' correctly* and I have to say I was left perplexed.

The site explained to use *like* in case of appearance and *as* more as a functional property of something/someone, for example:

> You act *like* a child.

and

> He works *as* a teacher.

Plus another explanation (*as .. as*, *look like*, ...) I thought I understood it.

But a few hours later I got to a situation where I wanted to say: "Let's do it as/like a team." and I don't know which one it should be.

I went through the whole site again, then checked some other sites, but I'm only finding clues which lead to both options, so I hope someone could help me to answer my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Let's do it as a team.

is the preferred version, though

> Let's do it like a team.

is also correct, and here is the difference in my understanding: the first version implies that the people in the question are a team, but they sometimes act not as a team or they might have different ideas about the same thing, but they are a team, and someone suggests to take advantage of that fact. The second version implies that the people are not a team, that's why someone suggests to imitate a team behavior - act like a team.

Comment: Thank you very much i had a feeling that I could use both but wasn't sure in what kind of situation.
Thank you once more, you got a bug out of my mind :).